# HttpURLConnection Unexpected status line

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection

Подключаюсь к web серверу через HttpURLConnection на Android.
Метод getResponseCode() выдает исключение:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: HTTP-Version: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

Если подключаться через браузер, то корректно страницу открывает Chrome. Firefox и Safari корректно ничего не отображают.
Подключаюсь к устройству (wifi датчику) для его настройки.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что проблема в status line  т.к. по стандарту в ней отсутствует  "HTTP-Version:", и корректная строка должна быть вида "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" ?

Comment: Да, проблема в строке состояния. Только в ошибке показано какая она пришла, а не какая должна быть. То есть в ней присутствует "HTTP-Version: " (само выражение)

Comment: @woesss т.е. пришла строка "HTTP-Version: HTTP/1.0 200 OK", а в идеале при успешном подключении должно приходить что-то такое "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" ? Запутался.

Comment: Да, именно так - сервер пишет в эту строку лишнее.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!